# Am I yotzei bikur cholim by visiting someone's Facebook page?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Since people increasingly live their lives online can I be yotzei the mitzvah of bikur cholim by visting the choleh's Facebook page?

---

**This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).**

Comment: I won't even get into the question of leket, shikcha and peah if you play farmville!

Comment: possibly related: does "tagging" someone of the opposite gender violate online n'giah?

Comment: Freebie for someone with a bit more creativity, knowledge, and/or will to nail this one than I: By visiting FB in the first place, you're [giving up some of your soul](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2011-09-28/news/ct-edit-facebook-20110928_1_mark-zuckerberg-facebook-future-social-network).

Comment: Oy, @none, what about "poking"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You only fulfill the mitzva if you poke the sick person's page, as the well known talmudic dictum states:

> **Poke** *chazi mai ima davar*
>   Go see what is happening

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/name-mi-yodeyas-chat-room#comment2582_1077 (but +1, great pun!)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this fulfills the *mitzva*. As [the *g'mara*](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=2121&size=1) says:

> כל המבקר חולה נוטל אחד, מששים בצערו
>
> Whoever visits a sick person washes one hand; they are feeling his pain.

Obviously this is not referring to visiting in person. As signs all over the hospital inform you, you should wash *both* hands when visiting in person. So it must be referring to visiting on Facebook.

Answer (score 8):

Well if the fellow is virtually sick then a virtual visit would be adequate. (Hilchos Internet Perek 27)

Comment: Can I find this on Hebrewbooks.org?

Comment: On hebrewbookspurimedition.com

Comment: Hebrewbooks has a Supreme Edition?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the state of the sick person.
If it's a case of Pikuach Nefesh or Sofeik PN, everything is allowed.
If the person is Chole kol Gufo, he probably is in bed where he will not be able to use his PC or laptop. 
If it's only miktzas chole, why do you want to visit him anyway?