# Are all Jews really Arabs?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The *Gemara* ([*Shevuos* 39a](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3957&size=2)) says

> כל ישראל ערבים
>
> All of Israel are Arabs.

Is this true?  I always thought that my family came from Eastern Europe.  If it is true that all Jews are actually Arabs, what is the best way to leverage this fact to help promote peace on earth?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14759

Answer (score 16):

The answer is the end of the statement, ערבים זה לזה, or Arabs to one another. Just as all the Arab nations are united in opposing Israel, Israel too is united as one people. World peace will ensue when the Arabs view the Jews as Arabs in relation to themselves as well. In fact, every evening we say ברוך אתה ה' המעריב ערבים, which expresses our desire for God to westernize the Arabs, so that we can achieve the blessing of אהבת עולם, worldwide love and harmony.

Comment: Are you sure it's not "who Arabizes the Arabs"? That seems like a more reasonable translation. This also doesn't give a practical solution for utilizing the fact to promote world peace.

Comment: I was gonna answer this post but I don't think I can do better than this. +1

Answer (score 5):

ערב means "mixture". Therefore we have to mix around the statement. Instead of "All of Israel are Arabs" we have "All of Israel [the Jewish nation] are **Sabra** [native Israelis]." So we see all Jews are not Arabs -- in fact just the opposite. Your second point is now moot.

Comment: I thought that Sabra specifically referred to the chiloni melting pot in Israel.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabra_(person)) says: Sabra (Hebrew: צבר‎, tzabar) is an informal slang term that refers to any Israeli Jew born on Israeli territory. [But it also says that it originally referred to the "New Jew".]

Answer (score 1):

Yisrael is refering to the land: All of Israel belongs to the Arabs

Comment: Why would the g'mara make such a claim?

Comment: It's purim torah, caused by drinking too much wine (or champagne-- Talmud Bubbly).

Comment: Maybe you mean "All of Israel has Arabs", y'know living, working, in every town.