# Why do we make a Bracha to Arabify the Arabs?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Every night we make a Bracha בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה יְהֹוָה, הַמַּעֲרִיב עֲרָבִים - which means to Arabify the Arabs.

Why do we care how Arabic are Arabs?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I thought it meant [westernize the Arabs](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69079/5151).

Answer (score 5):

When we pray for the Arabs to become more Arab, we mean for them to embrace the religion that they are most well known for; Islam. This is because as Rambam teaches us ([Hilkhot Melakhim 11:11](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/e511.htm)) Christianity and Islam were allowed to flourish in order to pave the way towards the ultimate proper acceptance of monotheism in the messianic age:

> וכל הדברים האלו של ישוע הנוצרי, ושל זה הישמעאלי שעמד אחריו--אינן אלא ליישר דרך למלך המשיח, ולתקן את העולם כולו לעבוד את ה' ביחד:  שנאמר "כי אז אהפוך אל עמים, שפה ברורה, לקרוא כולם בשם ה', ולעובדו שכם אחד" (ראה צפניה ג,ט).
>
> And all of these events involving Jesus the Nazarene, and this Ishmaelite who succeeded him [i.e. Mohammad]--they are only to prepare the way for the messianic king, and to improve the whole world to serve God together. As it says: 'For then will I turn to the peoples a pure language, that they may all call upon the name of the LORD, to serve Him with one consent.' ([Zephaniah 3:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2103.htm)).

It seems likely that intent isn't to all the elements of Islam, but to these positive elements that Rambam referenced.

Comment: It should be noted that the text of the prayer is very old. It is possible that when it was first established, Islam was considered an improvement relative to other popular religions and cults. Today, however, it might necessarily remain an improvement.

Comment: What about Christianity? Why don't we care how Christian Christians are according to this?

Comment: It's only a question according to your answer. For instance, it's ridiculous to ask about making the Hindus more Hindu or the Buddhists more Buddhist. But according to your answer that equates Islam with Christianity in respect to spreading monotheistic and messianic ideas, why do we focus more on Islam than Christianity? Another answer that explains Islam at the exclusion of Christianity wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: @DonielF a) I agree that's why I deleted my comment. b) Rambam says nothing about spreading Messianic ideas. c) The obvious answer is that theologically, Islam is superior to Christianity.

Comment: @DonielF Because Islam isn't *avodah zarah* while Christianity is.

Comment: how is this purim torah?