# How can I connect with God on facebook?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The purpose of *mitzvot* (Jewish commandments) is to connect with God so I tried to connect with Him on Facebook but didn't find Him. Can anyone help?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14756/759

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you can **try** to see G-d on Facebook, but you'd be committing suicide as it says:

Exodus 33:20:

> וַיֹּ֕אמֶר לֹ֥א תוּכַ֖ל לִרְאֹ֣ת אֶת־פָּנָ֑י כִּ֛י לֹֽא־יִרְאַ֥נִי
>   הָאָדָ֖ם וָחָֽי׃
>
> And He said: ‘Thou canst not see My **face**, for man shall not see Me and
>   live.’

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately, to connect on Facebook one must "friend" the other user, and ([Berachos 34a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=34&format=pdf)):

> חברותא כלפי שמיא מי איכא
>
> There is no such thing as a friend of Heaven

You'll have to find some other way to connect.

Comment: Maybe LinkedIn?

Comment: @SethJ I tried it as well, see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69184/11501)

Comment: @mbloch, that's unfortunate.

Answer (score 4):

God is everywhere. Unfortunately, at times, and [especially on Purim](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/the-concealed-face-of-god/), He is hiding His **face** ([*hester panim*](http://www.chabad.org/search/keyword_cdo/kid/10928/jewish/Hester-Panim.htm)) as it says ([Dvarim 31:19](http://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.31.18?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all))

> וְאָנֹכִ֗י הַסְתֵּ֨ר אַסְתִּ֤יר פָּנַי֙ בַּיּ֣וֹם הַה֔וּא
>   
> And **I will surely hide My face** on that day

Therefore God is not active on **facebook** these days.

I didn't find him on LinkedIn either but he might be outside my network. Check the [**Mechaber**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Ephraim_Karo) to see if he can **connect** you.

I did find God on [twitter](https://twitter.com/TheTweetOfGod?lang=en) but his [identity is not verified there](https://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/111-features/articles/119135-about-verified-accounts) so proceed with caution.

Comment: Perhaps more concerningly, the facebook account mentioned in [GreenAsJade's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69201/12176) _actually is_ marked as being verified...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem is.

He's easy to find there:

https://www.facebook.com/TheGoodLordAbove